# Can a ruby class method inherit from another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I read [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html) that a ruby class can only inherit from one class, and can `include` modules.

However, the devise module defines controllers like this:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  ...
end
```

Now, given that `Users` is probably a class, with `PasswordsController` being a method:

```
>> Devise::PasswordsController.class
=> Class
```

How is it that a method in a class inherits from another class?

Comment: According to my understanding, Users is a module and PasswordsController is the class which is inside app/controllers/users/passwords_controllers.rb

Comment: "given that Users is probably a class, with PasswordsController being a method" - I don't see where you got this idea from. First time seeing a nested class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
...
end
```

In the above code, Users is the module and PasswordsController is the class inside Users module. Similarly Devise is the module and PasswordsController is the class inside Devise module.

so when you run

```
Users::PasswordsController.class
#=> Class
Users.class
#=>Module
```

Answer (score 1):

What confuses you here is that you have wrong assumptions, namely:

---

> `Users` is probably a class

Not necessarily. Here we have namespace with nesting, therefore `Users` can be either a class or a module. In fact classes *are* modules.

---

> `PasswordsController` being a method

`PasswordsController` here is a class nested in the `Users` namespace. `::` simply lets you go one level into the nesting tree.

---

Consider:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

Foo::Bar.class # => class
```

Answer (score 0):

From Rails naming convention, `Users` is most probably a module, and `Users::PasswordsController` is a class.

Note that `::` is not for calling class methods (although it can be used this way). It's for accessing constants inside a module/class. For example

```
module Foo
  BAR = 'bar'
end

Foo::BAR
#=> "bar"
```

In Ruby, a module/class name is a constant, and the value stored in it is the module/class. So `::` also is used for accessing a module/class inside another module/class. For example

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

Foo::Bar
#=> Foo::Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Users and Device are modules, just used for scoping the real classes that are PasswordsController and PasswordsController.